# Как удалить в dataframe выбросы с помощью boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть [данные с выбросами](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ePZkLqqNiwvHzi3cRtMUayGU9p7g9y6/view?usp=sharing).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искала вариант удаления выбросов с помощью `boxplot`,
но не нашла способ применить [такой вариант](https://fooobar.com/questions/16952590/how-can-i-determine-and-remove-outliers-found-by-boxplot-in-python):

```
Q1 =  df['y'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df['y'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
df[(df['y'] < Q1-1.5*IQR ) | (df['y'] > Q1+1.5*IQR)]['y']
```

Это маска? Как с ее помощью изменить основной датасет, чтобы он был без выбросов по полю `y`, значения которого как выбросы надо удалить: меньше Q1-1,5 * IQR и выше Q3 + 1,5 * IQR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос некорректен - с помощью графика вы не сможете ничего убрать, только визуализировать.

Возможно, вам нужно это:

```
df_IQR = df[(df['y'] > Q1) & (df['y'] < Q3)]
df_IQR.boxplot(column="y")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Update:

Если применять исправленную формулу, а не обрезать прямо по квартилям, то получится так:

```
df_IQR = df[(df['y'] > (Q1-1.5*IQR)) & (df['y'] < (Q3+1.5*IQR))]
df_IQR.boxplot(column="y")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

**NOTE:**  в приведенной вами [ссылке](https://fooobar.com/questions/16952590/how-can-i-determine-and-remove-outliers-found-by-boxplot-in-python) ошибка в формуле:

```
(df['col_name'] < Q1-1.5*IQR ) | (df['col_name'] > Q1+1.5*IQR)
# NOTE: ------------------------------------------> ^
```

[правильная формула](https://towardsdatascience.com/ways-to-detect-and-remove-the-outliers-404d16608dba):

```
(df['col_name'] < Q1-1.5*IQR ) | (df['col_name'] > Q3+1.5*IQR)
# NOTE: ------------------------------------------> ^
```

Картинка объясняющая формулу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Решение:**

Можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) - мне кажется условия запроса так легче читаются и воспринимаются:

```
df.query("@Q1 - 1.5*@IQR < y < @Q3 + 1.5*@IQR").boxplot(column="y")
```

Comment: Сама формула запроса несколько странная, принимая во внимание нужды автора вопроса. Почему полтора межквартильных вокруг первой квартили , а не медианы?

Comment: @strawdog, если хотите разобраться с этим - советую задать новый вопрос ;)